# Compute Christoffel symbols of a rotating cartesian coordinate system

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, connections

Suppose we have a smooth manifold $(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{R}^4}, \{(\mathbb{R}^3,x),(\mathbb{R}^3,y)\},\nabla,t)$ where $t:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is such that $t(a,b,c,d)=a$, $x=Id_{\mathbb{R}^3}$, $\nabla$ is such that in the chart $(\mathbb{R}^3,x)$ the connection coefficients ${\Gamma_{(x)}} ^{a}_{bc} =0$ and $y$ is defined through the identities 
$$t=x^0=y^0$$
$$x^1=y^1\cos\theta-y^2\sin\theta$$
$$x^2=y^1\sin\theta+y^2\cos\theta$$
for some $\theta=\omega t$ where $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$. This structure attempts to model a three dimensional Newtonian spacetime with an inertial chart and to identify which coefficients of the connection in the non-inertial chart are different than zero. In my computation of the connection coefficients I realized my understanding of differential geometry is very bad. I found $\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^0}=0$ and $\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^1}=\cos\theta$ which implies
$$\frac{\partial^2 x^1}{\partial y^1 \partial y^0}=0\neq-\omega\sin\theta=\frac{\partial^2 x^1}{\partial y^0\partial y^1}$$
Why don't my partial derivatives commute?
Any extra help on calculating the coefficients is greatly appreciate. If anybody knows of any textbooks that give a formal treatment of Newtonian space time, the information would be very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you forgot that $\theta$ depends on $y^0$ when you computed $\dfrac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^0}$. The correct answer should be
$$\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^0} = -\omega(y^1\sin\theta+y^2\cos\theta),$$
and then
$$\frac{\partial^2 x^1}{\partial y^1\partial y^0} = -\omega\sin\theta,$$
as you desired.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same. The problem is that $y^0=x^0$ and therefore $\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^0}=\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^0}=\partial_0(x^1\circ x^{-1})\circ x= \partial_0(x^1)=0$

Comment: I saw it! The thing is that the two derivatives are different because even though the functions are the same, they are in different charts

Comment: Right. What you said in your first comment is incorrect. (Try computing derivatives in the charts $(x,y)$ and $(x,x+y)$, for example, on $\Bbb R^2$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I just noted your user name and I must say I'm honored with your reply. The videos on youtube of the course Math 3510 really inspired me to learn the proper mathematics to enhance my physics major. Once again, thanks!

Comment: @IvánMauricioBurbano, you're most welcome. Keep learning, and keep me posted!